# Maintaining separate folders various project files in Finder

Tags: xcode4

I'm trying to keep my Xcode project organized. I want to maintain separate folders for xib  files and class .h/.m files when creating the files or a new project. I'm talking about separate folders in Finder, not in Xcode's File Navigator.

The problem that I'm facing is that it seems that when I put all my xibs into a folder, and then I edit the xib in Xcode, the changes are not reflected when I run the app.

Can anyone shed some light on this? How do I maintain separate folders in Finder, but let Xcode organize the files too?

Comment: You can keep them together on hard disk, and use XCode file group.

Comment: I want in In System hardisk folder but not in xcode's left Navigator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create 2 new groups named classes and xib files.And after u creating your classes,just drag the xib files to the xib files folder and the .h and .m files to the classes folder.its quite simple!

Answer (score 1):

1) Create groups in your Xcode

2)Whenever you add new file first select group( which group that want to add file for)and than add file.

3)Than after if some files outside of groups than remove it reference from Xcode and create new reference after selecting group type.

4)or you can create groups folder in hard disk and than after you have to create reference according to group folder in Xcode.

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: new files are saved in group . but xib file are also in the same group, along with m,h files

Comment: Yep from the above you maintain your ,h,.m, and xib file as well images according your requirements..

Comment: I used to create 2 file ok, But after drag the xib files in to xib folders, if i change size,pos of any obj / add any object like button it doesn't effect on code means it doesn't displays after execution,

Comment: I don't know what do you want to do actually. But i can say group doesn't make any effect in xib. Whatever in xib remains as it is.

Comment: Note:I want in  In System hardisk folder but not in xcode's left Navigator any way thanks ur anser sutable for xcode navigator, nice 1

Answer (score 1):

In your xcode right click on project name -> create new group and create a folder, give the name that you want and you can drag your files to that folder, this way you can maintain seperate folders in your xcode

Comment: he's not adding existing files, he's creating new files from Xcode

Comment: @IOSDev I used to create 2 file ok, But after drag the xib files in to xib folders, if i change size,pos of any obj / add any object like button it doesn't effect on code means it doesn't displays after execution,

Answer (score 1):

If you want fileStructure in hardisk but not in XCode navigator,
you need to create your folder in your project folder, just after project creation.
Then when you create new file, xcode ask where to save those files, just select one of the folder you created earlier.

Comment: new files are saved in newfolder . but xib file are also in the same group, along with m,h files, I need to separate folder for xib

Comment: Delete reference in xcode. Move your xib in separate folder, and and new reference to xcode